# filter out rows if one column value is associated with only one single value in another column

Tags: sql, oracle

```
A   B   C   D   E
1981    a   b   CY3 2
1981    c   l   CY3 1
1981    f   r   CY3 5
1255    ee  ee  CY3 1
1255    ff  ff  CY3 1
1387    g   g   CY5 2
1387    h   h   CY5 10
1387    P   h   CY5 C7
```

I am getting this table with the following query (ORACLE pl/sql):

```
SELECT A,B,C,D,COUNT(*) AS E
FROM TAB1  t1 INNER JOIN TAB2 t2 ON t1.A = t2.B
             INNER JOIN TAB3 t3 ON t1.A = t3.C
GROUP BY A,B,C,D
ORDER BY D ASC, A DESC;
```

And I would like to get the following result by editing the above query:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1981    a   b   CY3 2
1981    c   l   CY3 1
1981    f   r   CY3 5
1255    ee  ee  CY3 1
1255    ff  ff  CY3 1
```

I would like to filter out the last three rows because the column D has one value (i.e. CY5) which is associated with only one single value in column A (i.e. 1387) whereas CY3 is associated with two different values (i.e. 1981 & 12550 so I wan to keep this).

Can anyone help me or point me to a similar question please?

Comment: why don't you just add: WHERE D != 'CY5'

Comment: @EstebanP. that would be hard coding,.

Comment: exactly it would not fix the general case..

Answer (score 1):

Most DBMSes support *Windowed Aggregates*:

```
select *
from
 (
    SELECT A,B,C,D,COUNT(*) AS E,
       MIN(A) OVER (PARTITION BY D) AS minA,-- minimum A for all rows with the same D
       MAX(A) OVER (PARTITION BY D) AS maxA -- maximum A for all rows with the same D
    FROM TAB1  t1 INNER JOIN TAB2 t2 ON t1.A = t2.B
                 INNER JOIN TAB3 t3 ON t1.A = t3.C
    GROUP BY A,B,C,D
 ) as dt
where minA <> maxA -- there must be at least 2 different values (usually cheaper than COUNT(DISTINCT)
ORDER BY D ASC, A DESC;
```

Edit:

For Oracle and as you want to return the number of distinct values:

```
select *
from
 (
    SELECT A,B,C,D,COUNT(*) AS E,
       COUNT(DISTINCT A) OVER (PARTITION BY D) AS countA
    FROM TAB1  t1 INNER JOIN TAB2 t2 ON t1.A = t2.B
                 INNER JOIN TAB3 t3 ON t1.A = t3.C
    GROUP BY A,B,C,D
 ) dt -- you don't need the alias in Oracle, but STandard SQL requires it
where countA > 1
ORDER BY D ASC, A DESC;
```

Comment: 00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"..on line: " ) as dt"

Comment: I am using sqldeveloper pl/sql on win10

Comment: it works without as.. I mean " ) dt" instead of " ) as dt"

Comment: *sqldeveloper pl/sql*: this (and the error message) answers the question which DBMS you're using, Oracle :-) Due to unknown reason Oracle doesn't support the `AS` for a table alias.

Comment: what if I wanted to remove from the final result the minA and maxA values?

Comment: The min/max aggregate functions could be consolidated into a single `count(distinct a) over (partition by d)`, which you could then check is greater than 1 in the outer query;

Comment: @Boneist: Not all DBMSes support DISTINCT for Windowed Aggregates and MIN/MAX is usually more efficient.

Comment: @FrancescoDassisis: You simply replace `*` with the columns you want to return :-)

Comment: it works and it is even better since the client wants to know the number of associated A values for each D.. that's perfect like this thanks everybody..

Comment: @FrancescoDassisis: adding important information like this (and the DBMS) from the beginning would be really helpfull

Comment: @dnoeth as this appears to be an Oracle question, `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` is perfectly ok. As for whether it's more efficient or not, that's for the OP to test with their data. I would argue that using `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` would make the intention clearer, and thus make the code more self-documenting (and therefore more maintainable).

Comment: @Boneist: Of course, I already added it to my answer, but when I answered the question was only tagged with `sql` :-)

Comment: sorry I didn't include Oracle info in my question

Answer (score 0):

use correlated subquery using exists

```
SELECT A,B,C,D,COUNT(*) AS E
FROM TABLESS t1
where exists (select 1 from TABLESS t2 where t1.D=t2.D having count(A)>1)
GROUP BY A,B,C,D
ORDER BY D ASC, A DESC
```

Comment: what if ABLESS is actually TAB1 INNER JOIN TAB2.. I need to alias the whole joined table.. thanks

Comment: @FrancescoDassisis, what is your dbms name

Comment: sorry what do you mean?

Comment: @FrancescoDassisis, what database r u using?

Comment: Oracle sql developer pl/sql

Answer (score 0):

Have a look!

```
    DECLARE @TEST AS TABLE
(A VARCHAR(100),B VARCHAR(100),C VARCHAR(100),D VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @TEST VALUES
('1981','A','B','CY3'),
('1981','A','B','CY3'),
('1981','C','L','CY3'),
('1981','F','R','CY3'),
('1981','F','R','CY3'),
('1981','F','R','CY3'),
('1981','F','R','CY3'),
('1981','F','R','CY3'),
('1255','EE','EE','CY3'),
('1255','FF','FF','CY3'),
('1387','G','G','CY5'),
('1387','G','G','CY5'),
('1387','H','H','CY5'),
('1387','H','H','CY5'),
('1387','H','H','CY5'),
('1387','H','H','CY5'),
('1387','H','H','CY5'),
('1387','H','H','CY5'),
('1387','H','H','CY5'),
('1387','H','H','CY5'),
('1387','H','H','CY5'),
('1387','H','H','CY5'),
('1387','P','H','CY5'),
('1387','P','H','CY5'),
('1387','P','H','CY5'),
('1387','P','H','CY5'),
('1387','P','H','CY5'),
('1387','P','H','CY5'),
('1387','P','H','CY5')

SELECT DATA.* FROM 
(
SELECT T.D,COUNT(T.A) AS DISTINCT_RECORD FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT D,A FROM @TEST) T
GROUP BY T.D
HAVING COUNT(T.A)>1
) 

CRITERIA LEFT JOIN 

(
SELECT A,B,C,D,COUNT(*) AS E
FROM @TEST
GROUP BY A,B,C,D
) 

DATA ON CRITERIA.D=DATA.D
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with s (a, b, c, d, e) as (
select 1981, 'a'  , 'b' , 'CY3', 2  from dual union all
select 1981, 'c'  , 'l' , 'CY3', 1  from dual union all
select 1981, 'f'  , 'r' , 'CY3', 5  from dual union all
select 1255, 'ee' , 'ee', 'CY3', 1  from dual union all
select 1255, 'ff' , 'ff', 'CY3', 1  from dual union all
select 1387, 'g'  , 'g' , 'CY5', 2  from dual union all
select 1387, 'h'  , 'h' , 'CY5', 10 from dual union all
select 1387, 'P'  , 'h' , 'CY5', 17 from dual)
select a, b, c, d, e
from 
    (select s.*, count(distinct a) over (partition by d) cnt_dict
     from s
    )
where cnt_dict > 1;

         A B  C  D            E
---------- -- -- --- ----------
      1255 ee ee CY3          1
      1255 ff ff CY3          1
      1981 f  r  CY3          5
      1981 c  l  CY3          1
      1981 a  b  CY3          2
```